# List of columns in sql query

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc

I have a query using various joins, and I just need the list of columns which are returned by this query. I done it in java, by asking only one row with rownum=1 and getting column name for value.The problem is if there is no data returned by that query.

For ex.

```
select * from something
```

and if there is any data returning by this query then it will return `col1`,`col2`,`col3`.
But if there is no data returned by this query, then it will throw error.

What I need is

Is there any way that I can run

```
desc (select * from something)
```

or similar to get list of columns returned by query.

It can be in sql or JAVA. Both methods are acceptable.

**In my application, user passes the query, and I can add wrapper to the query but I cant modify it totally.**

The flow of application is

query from user -> execute by java and get one row -> return list of columns in the result set.

Comment: `select * from something` will ***not*** "throw an error" if the table does not contain any data. How and where are you running this?

Comment: The query will not throw error, But if I try to get first row of the resultset, it will throw error as record is not available

Comment: No, it will **not** throw an error if you do it correctly. Please show us your Java code.

Comment: a_horse_with_no_name is correct; the most sensible way to get the metadata for an arbitrary query is to do it in Java, which you should be able to do whether there are rows returned by the query or not.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, query will not throw error, but java will as result set array length is 0 and I am accessing first element.

Comment: Again: if you do it *correctly* it won't throw an exception. Show us your Java code.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, I tried the same as http://stackoverflow.com/a/31914497/2034794, and it is returning empty result set, and this causing error in further application.

Comment: So you have a different error in your application that's nothing to do with obtaining the column metadata then?

Comment: "*and this causing error in further application*" - then this "further application" has a serious bug. But that is a totally different question. Using `ResultSetMetaData` is the right way to obtain the column information.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, yes, there was a bug in further code also. Thanks your help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can use [ResultSetMetaData](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html)  of resultset

for example :

```
 ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT a, b, c FROM TABLE2"); 
 ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();  
 int countOfColumns = rsmd.getColumnCount();
 for(int i = 1; i <= countOfColumns ; i++  )
 System.out.println(rsmd.getColumnName(i));
```

Comment: Tried this method, Thanks, but `rs` is empty if there are no records.

Comment: @LaxmikantDange: even if `rs` is empty, you can still get the metadata.

Answer (score 0):

you could maybe convert your query to a view, you can then see the columns in the view by querying user_tab_columns

```
select * from user_tab_columns
```

Answer (score 0):

The Oracle equivalent for information_schema.COLUMNS is USER_TAB_COLS for tables owned by the current user, ALL_TAB_COLS or DBA_TAB_COLS for tables owned by all users.

Tablespace is not equivalent to a schema, neither do you have to provide the tablespace name.

Providing the schema/username would be of use if you want to query ALL_TAB_COLS or DBA_TAB_COLS for columns OF tables owned by a specific user. in your case, I'd imagine the query would look something like:

```
String sqlStr= "

   SELECT column_name

   FROM   all_tab_cols

   WHERE  table_name = 'users'

   AND owner = ' || +_db+ || '

   AND column_name NOT IN ( 'password', 'version', 'id' )
   "
```

Note that with this approach, you risk SQL injection.

Comment: If you're doing this you need to capitalise the TABLE_NAME and COLUMN_NAME. It also wont work for an arbitrary query - which is what  the OP is attempting (note the text about JOINs at the top of the question)